# After using the navigateurl() in angular url changing but not loading automatically and need to give an enter manually after the url change

Tags: javascript, angular

## After using the navigateurl() in angular url changing but not loading automatically and need to give an enter manually after the url change`your text**your text**`

## this.router.navigateurl(url);

Need to open the url automatically after thr url changed

## After using the navigateurl() in angular url changing but not loading automatically and need to give an enter manually after the url change`your text**your text**`

## this.router.navigateurl(url);

Need to open the url automatically after thr url changed

Comment: You are more likely to get useful responses if you provide a complete code example.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.